# Codeigniter does not redirect input form to Dashboard when clicked on the button

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

the user name and password on the login form, even if the information is correct dashboarda is not refreshing itself, I wonder what is the problem. If the information is correct, the dashboarda redirect the information is not correct, leave the message on the page, how can you help

**MY CODES**

File:Login View

```
<div class="metro double-size green">
    <form>
        <div class="input-append lock-input">
            <?php if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;?>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Username" name="Username">
            <span class="text-warning">  </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="metro double-size yellow">
    <form>
        <div class="input-append lock-input">
            <input type="password" class="" placeholder="Password" name="Password">
            <span class="text-warning"> <?php echo form_error('password');?> </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="metro single-size terques login">
    <form>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url("main/process"); ?>" class="btn login-btn" name="process" value="Login">
            Login
            <i class=" icon-long-arrow-right"></i>
        </a>

    </form>
</div>
```

**MY CODES**

File:Main_Controller.

```
public function index($msg = NULL){
    // Load our view to be displayed
    // to the user
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}

public function process(){
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('Login_model');
    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->Login_model->validate();
    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $this->index();
    }else{
        // If user did validate,
        // Send them to members area
        redirect('main');
    }
}
```

**MY CODES**

File:Login_Model

```
 public function validate(){
    // grab user input
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

    // Prep the query
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    // Let's check if there are any results
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        // If there is a user, then create session data
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
            'userid' => $row->userid,
            'fname' => $row->fname,
            'lname' => $row->lname,
            'username' => $row->username,
            'validated' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    // If the previous process did not validate
    // then return false.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This may be of some interest to you (unrelated): `$this->input->input_stream('key', TRUE); // XSS Clean`. And please please please don't store unhashed passwords ... that's just asking for trouble

Comment: Add all fields into single form. Dont use multiple form tag